# Hey , I am just started to code in android and getting error Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast in android

Tags: java, android, permissions

```
permission denial
```

My activity code is

```
boolean isEnable= Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,0)==1;
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON,isEnable?0:1);
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
intent.putExtra("state",!isEnable);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: and the permission i provide in android.manifest.xml are
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Answer (score 1):

That is because ordinary SDK apps cannot send `ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED` broadcasts. If you look at [the documentation for that `Intent` action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED), you will see:

> This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Also note that your `AIRPLANE_MODE_ON` stuff [may not work on API Level 17 (Android 4.2) or higher devices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON).

And, note that ordinary SDK apps cannot hold the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission. If you are building your own custom Android ROM, you could have apps that hold that permission in that ROM.

Comment: Thanks for reply
So how can i use it on API Level 17 or higher devices?

Comment: @abhibhardwaj: AFAIK, you can't. AFAIK, `Settings.Global` (where `AIRPLANE_MODE_ON` moved) requires `WRITE_SETTINGS`, which ordinary SDK apps cannot hold.